# Firefox "An attempt was made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces"

Tags: javascript, firefox

why does `element.setAttributeNS(null, attrName, attrValue)` give this error in Firefox but not in Chrome ?

Comment: My firefox version is 7.0.1, it happily accepted it, no errors.

Comment: Does your error in FF happen for _all_ values of `attrName` and `attrValue` or only for something specific? What about for a non-null first param?

Comment: yep, found the problem, it's when you try to set xmlns, as in s.setAttributeNS(null, "xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to get this with the above code is if `attrName` contains a `':'` in it, since that would in fact create an invalid DOM (an attribute in the null namespace with a nonempty namespace prefix).

I that's what you're doing, I have no idea why Chrome doesn't throw.  http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-element-setattributens step 5 says to throw the exception in question and is quite clear.